# Same drop shadow on every li when using columns

Tags: html, css

In my website I have a part where I'm using an amount of li's depending on how many entries there are.

So lets say there are 3 entries, 3 li's will be generated. When there are 4 entries 4 li's will be generated and so on. What I did is give my ul a `columns` value which changes depending on how many entries there are.

This all works flawless. However what I want now is to draw a drop shadow on every li. When I try to do this only the last li is effected the way it should be. Does anyone know how I can change this?

my li's are of the `class` `item`. and the `css` I tried to apply to it is as follows

```
.item{width:100%; max-width: 290px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
```

Hope someone will be able to tell me how to solve my problem

**EDIT**

As requested here is an example of what happens.
https://jsfiddle.net/x0u9xao0/

Comment: Please share html code snippet

Comment: I guess that since `<li>` items are block and stack vertically,  the problem is that the bottom `<li>` items cover the bottom shadow of their respective top `<li>` item

Comment: @niyasc I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the columns stop at the bottom of the element, so you couldn't see the bottom shadow (which was below that)
Adding a `margin-bottom` to each of the list elements meant that the column went on for some more, so you can see the bottom shadow
See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0u9xao0/1/)